# Avoid necessity of copying data when querying from SQL and MongoDB

Tags: sql, mongodb, architecture

In a web application consisting of several back end services, there are two services owning different properties for the same data entities.
E.g. Service A holds in an **SQL** database:

```
| id      | a   |
|:--------|:---------|
| id1   | 5   |
| id2   | 17   |
...
```

and Service B holds in **MongoDB**:

```
[ 
  {id: "id1", b: 50}, 
  {id: "id2", b: 456},
  ... 
]
```

(`id1` and `id2` are referring to the very same real-life entities).

Now, in Service B, the requirement is: Sum up properties `a` and `b`, sort by the result, and return the first 100 entries.

Now, the naive approach would be to handle that on application level, i.e. fetch all data from Service A (whether through an API or directly from its database), fetch all data from the Service B database, and then match and calculate the results.
However, performance is crucial here and if there are millions of entries, it becomes way too slow to fetch all data each time from the DBs.
Instead, this should be handled in a query in the DB.

Question is: How?

As far as I know, there is no such thing as a "Foreign Data Wrapper" for MongoDB which would allow to natively query an SQL database from within MongoDB?

Of course, it would be possible to copy the data from Service A to Service B, resulting in a structure like `[ {id: "id1", a: 5, b: 50}, {id: "id2", a: 17, b: 456} ... ]` and the necessity to keep data in sync.

So, question is: Am I overlooking anything here? Can this be solved easier than by copying data?

Comment: initial thoughts, 1) a single source of truth is probably best. 2) if #1 can't happen, perhaps a data sync (doesn't necessarily mean data copy). A separate job/bus could do this regularly - triggered at some interval or as data changes depending on the use case. this can also improve performance. with materialized views for example, results can be pre-computed (granted, this is effectively a data copy). 3) consider carefully that the current design doesn't seem to support the requirement. collaborate with Service B Team if it isn't yours. 4) manage a more complete entity with a 3rd service